# Not getting the correct results back from program

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python, trying to put my knowledge of Python to the test. I'm creating a program where you are given your grade, after inserting your name. coursework mark & prelim mark. The program doesn't bring out the correct Grade as a result, I don't know why..

```
#Written by Bobby O


#def Get_Details():
Student_Name = input("Enter the name of the student: ")
Coursework_Mark = int(input("Enter the coursework mark achieved by the student: "))
while Coursework_Mark < 0 or Coursework_Mark >60:
   print("Try again, remember the coursework mark is out of 60.")
   Coursework_Mark = int(input("Enter the coursework mark achieved by the student: "))

Prelim_Mark = int(input("Enter the prelim mark achieved by the student: "))
while Prelim_Mark < 0 or Prelim_Mark > 90:
    print("Try again, remember the prelim mark is out of 90.")
    Prelim_Mark = int(input("Enter the prelim mark achieved by the student: "))

#return Student_Name, Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark

#def Calculate_Percentage(Coursework_Mark, Prelim_Mark):
   Percentage = ((Coursework_Mark + Prelim_Mark)/150) * 100

if Percentage >= 70:
   Grade = "A"
elif Percentage >= 60 or Percentage <= 69:
   Grade = "B"
elif Percentage >= 50 or Percentage <= 59:
   Grade = "C"
elif Percentage >= 45 or Percentage <= 49:
   Grade = "D"
else:
   Grade = "No Award"

#return Percentage, Grade


#def Display_Results(Student_Name, Grade):
print(Student_Name + " achieved a grade " + Grade)
```

Comment: What is the actual output of the program and how does it differ from your expected output?

Comment: Also, there's a small bug -- I think this like `while Prelim_Mark < 0 or Coursework_Mark >90:` should be `while Prelim_Mark < 0 or Prelim_Mark > 90:`

Comment: Your indentation is screwed up in places, but that might be copy/paste errors. For instance, your while loops are both infinite.

Comment: For example, I enter 30 (as my coursework mark ) & 45 (as my prelim mark ) - which is ((30+40)) / 15 ) * 100 = 50% which is equivalent to a C but my instead it will say B.

Comment: Oops, I ment 45 in the calculatio no 40 but yeah. When I inserted these numbers, the wrong grade came up.

Comment: @mattm Thank you, it's been corrected.

Comment: You want to use `and` instead of `or` in your `elif`. Better, use the pythonic `elif 50 <= Percentage <= 59:` and so on.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger THANK YOU! That was the issue, all is well now - THANKS! :)

Comment: In your if/else statements for checking the grade, you can drop the `or` portion of all the statements because of the conditions being checked.
ie. If it's 70% or above, it will be an A (and then the if statements are terminated), so on the next check for between 60% and 69% you don't need the upper bound of 69% because if it was higher than 69% it would have aleady been met by the prior if statement, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `or` when testing the bounds, and you should be using `and`.

```
elif Percentage >= 60 or Percentage <= 69:
   Grade = "B"
```

In this case, if `Percentage` is `50`, then `Percentage <= 69` will return `True`.

You don't want to check if the number is greater than 60 OR less than 69. You want to check if it is *between* those two values, so you should be doing:

```
elif Percentage >= 60 and Percentage <= 69:
    Grade = "B"
```

(This applies to all of your boundary checks)

Comment: It’s even better to check `elif 60 <= Percentage < 70:`